# Sugar crm soap api

Tags: c#, sugarcrm

hi I am integrating the Sugar CRM Version 6.5.24 to my visual studio, i am truing to get all contact  in the Sugar CRM, i am tyring a method 
for that get_entry_list

SugarClient.get_entry_list(SessionId, ModuleName, query, "", 0, fields, null, accountsCount, 0);

where SugarCLient is object if sugarsoap with SessionID, Modulename is Contacts, query is the filter of to and from date, orderby is blank, offset is 0 fiels are to contact to be selected, next is link_name_to_field array which is null, next is maxresults which is int that is max value of contact, last is deleted which is zero, here the prolem is when i am trying to execute i am getting error "The specified type was not recognized: name='link_list', namespace='http://www.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm', at ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the Solution, we need to use the Soap API version V4.1
Example: http://127.0.0.1:82/sugarcrm/service/v4_1/soap.php?wsdl
in this there is one extra parameter logtrace we need to pass 1 to capture log and 0 if we don't need the log.